# SOLR8.4.0 - SolrWriter Warning "Error Creating Document" but no information as to why

Tags: solr, solr8

SOLR is not processing all my records during data import for some reason. Also, I have no idea why &#8203 is being appended to everything. It seems the id isn't being found in the import? But it's definitely part of the view solr is referencing... Below is the solr log reported in the browser (as you can see, there is not error or reason why it doesn't process). I also checked the solr.log on the server and it's empty.

Fetched: 86,424

Skipped: 0

Processed: 39,622

```
Error creating document : SolrInputDocument(fields: [Is_Arra=Yes,&#8203; Org_Code__TYPE_LIST=51411,&#8203; Total_Service_In-Kind_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS=0,&#8203; Total_Partner_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS=0,&#8203; Project_Status__TYPE_LIST=Completed,&#8203; Total_Non-1121_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS=0,&#8203; Project_Name=Long Project Name,&#8203; Is_Planning=No,&#8203; Has_Photo=false,&#8203; Total_Partner_In-Kind_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS=0,&#8203; Project_Acres=0.8421747005051416,&#8203; Last_Updated_By__TYPE_LIST=name,&#8203; user,&#8203; id=48384,&#8203; Project_ID=48384,&#8203; Org_Type__TYPE_LIST=ECOS,&#8203; Total_1124_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS=0,&#8203; Org_Type_Acronym__TYPE_LIST=ESFO,&#8203; Arra_ID=R5EB,&#8203; Last_Updated_Date__TYPE_DATE__FORMAT_DATE=2010-09-02 00:00:00.0,&#8203; Total_Accomplishment_Miles=4.999516749131982,&#8203; Creation_Date__TYPE_DATE__FORMAT_DATE=2008-03-31 00:00:00.0,&#8203; Narrative=Short Narrative,&#8203; Total_1121_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS=0,&#8203; Total_Service_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS=0,&#8203; Is_Nrcs=No,&#8203; Total_Accomplishment_Acres=0.0,&#8203; Org_Name__TYPE_LIST=ECOS Service,&#8203; Public_Narrative=Public Narrative,&#8203; Completion_Date__TYPE_DATE__FORMAT_DATE=2010-09-29 00:00:00.0,&#8203; Point_Of_Contact__TYPE_LIST=name,&#8203; user,&#8203; State__TYPE_LIST=VA,&#8203; Total_Accomplishment_Structures=1,&#8203; Total_Service_Staff_Days=0,&#8203; Region__TYPE_LIST=5,&#8203; Mechanism_ID__TYPE_LIST=51888,&#8203; Mechanism_Name__TYPE_LIST=Mech Name,&#8203; _version_=1675563021844348928])
```

**db-data-config**

```
<entity name="project"  transformer="TemplateTransformer" 
                query="select distinct * from habits4.solr_project">
            <field column="project_id" name="id"/> <!-- needed for 1-to-many's -->
            <field column="project_id" name="Project_ID"/>
            <field column="project_name" name="Project_Name"/>
            <field column="descriptive_name" name="Project_Descriptive_Name"/>
            <field column="po_orgcode" name="Org_Code__TYPE_LIST"/>
            <field column="po_orgname" name="Org_Name__TYPE_LIST"/>
            <field column="po_region" name="Region__TYPE_LIST"/>
            <field column="po_mailstateabbr" name="State__TYPE_LIST"/>
            <field column="orgtype" name="Org_Type__TYPE_LIST"/>
            <field column="orgtypeacro" name="Org_Type_Acronym__TYPE_LIST"/>
            <field column="project_status" name="Project_Status__TYPE_LIST"/>
            <field column="completion_date" name="Completion_Date__TYPE_DATE__FORMAT_DATE" dateTimeFormat='yyyy-mm-dd'/>
            <field column="poc_fullname" name="Point_Of_Contact__TYPE_LIST"/>
            <field column="is_planning" name="Is_Planning"/>
            <field column="is_public" name="Is_Public"/>
            <field column="is_arra" name="Is_Arra"/>
            <field column="is_nrcs" name="Is_Nrcs"/>
            <field column="arra_id" name="Arra_ID"/>
            <field column="narrative" name="Narrative"/>
            <field column="public_narrative" name="Public_Narrative"/>
            <field column="created" name="Creation_Date__TYPE_DATE__FORMAT_DATE" dateTimeFormat='yyyy-mm-dd'/>
            <field column="created_by" name="Created_By__TYPE_LIST"/>
            <field column="last_updated" name="Last_Updated_Date__TYPE_DATE__FORMAT_DATE" dateTimeFormat='yyyy-mm-dd'/>
            <field column="last_updated_by" name="Last_Updated_By__TYPE_LIST"/>            
            <field column="geom_type" name="Geometry_Type"/>
            <field column="project_acres" name="Project_Acres"/>
            <field column="total_accomp_acres" name="Total_Accomplishment_Acres"/>
            <field column="total_accomp_miles" name="Total_Accomplishment_Miles"/>
            <field column="total_accomp_structures" name="Total_Accomplishment_Structures"/>
            <field column="total_service_staff_days" name="Total_Service_Staff_Days"/>
            <field column="total_service_amount" name="Total_Service_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS"/>
            <field column="total_service_in_kind_amount" name="Total_Service_In-Kind_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS"/>
            <field column="total_partner_amount" name="Total_Partner_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS"/>
            <field column="total_partner_in_kind_amount" name="Total_Partner_In-Kind_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS"/>
            <field column="total_1121_amount" name="Total_1121_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS"/>
            <field column="total_non_1121_amt" name="Total_Non-1121_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS"/>
            <field column="total_1124_amount" name="Total_1124_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS"/>
            <field column="total_non_1124_amt" name="Total_Non-1124_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS"/>
            <field column="has_photo" name="Has_Photo"/>
            <entity name="mechanisms" dataSource="habitsProjectDataSource" transformer="TemplateTransformer" query="SELECT * FROM habits4.solr_project_mechanisms_metadata WHERE project_id=${project.project_id}">
                <field column="mechanism_id" name="Mechanism_ID__TYPE_LIST"/>
                <field column="mechanism_name" name="Mechanism_Name__TYPE_LIST"/>
            </entity>
            <entity name="monitorings" dataSource="habitsProjectDataSource" transformer="TemplateTransformer" query="SELECT * FROM habits4.solr_project_monitorings_metadata WHERE project_id=${project.project_id}">
                <field column="monitoring_id" name="Monitoring_ID__TYPE_LIST"/>
                <field column="visit_date" name="Visit_Date__TYPE_DATE__FORMAT_DATE" dateTimeFormat='yyyy-mm-dd'/>
                <field column="maint_activities_occurring" name="Are_Maintenance_Activities_Occurring__TYPE_LIST"/>
                <field column="landowner_objectives_met" name="Are_Landowner_Objectives_Met__TYPE_LIST"/>
                <field column="species_objectives_met" name="Are_Species_Objectives_Met__TYPE_LIST"/>
                <field column="habitat_objective_success" name="Are_Habitat_Objectives_Met__TYPE_LIST"/>
            </entity>
        </entity>
```

**schema**

```
<fields>
        <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="status" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" />
        <field name="text" type="text_en" stored="false" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
    
        <field name="office_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Project_ID" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Project_Name" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Project_Descriptive_Name" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Project_Status__TYPE_LIST" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Org_Code__TYPE_LIST" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Org_Name__TYPE_LIST" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Org_Type__TYPE_LIST" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Org_Type_Acronym__TYPE_LIST" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Region__TYPE_LIST" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="State__TYPE_LIST" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Has_Photo" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Completion_Date__TYPE_DATE__FORMAT_DATE" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Point_Of_Contact__TYPE_LIST" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Is_Planning" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Is_Public" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Is_Arra" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Is_Nrcs" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Arra_ID" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Narrative" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Public_Narrative" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Creation_Date__TYPE_DATE__FORMAT_DATE" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Created_By__TYPE_LIST" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Last_Updated_Date__TYPE_DATE__FORMAT_DATE" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Last_Updated_By__TYPE_LIST" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Geometry_Type__TYPE_LIST" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Project_Acres" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Total_Accomplishment_Acres" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Total_Accomplishment_Miles" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Total_Accomplishment_Structures" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Total_Service_Staff_Days" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Total_Service_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Total_Service_In-Kind_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Total_Partner_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Total_Partner_In-Kind_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Total_1121_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Total_Non-1121_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Total_1124_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Total_Non-1124_Amount__FORMAT_DOLLARS" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        
    <field name="Mechanism_ID__TYPE_LIST" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="Mechanism_Name__TYPE_LIST" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>        
        
    <field name="Monitoring_ID__TYPE_LIST" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
        <field name="Visit_Date__TYPE_DATE__FORMAT_DATE" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Are_Maintenance_Activities_Occurring__TYPE_LIST" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Are_Landowner_Objectives_Met__TYPE_LIST" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Are_Species_Objectives_Met__TYPE_LIST" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="Are_Habitat_Objectives_Met__TYPE_LIST" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    </fields>
```

I've tried using and removing the `<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>` but no change.

Comment: The log should not be empty - it should show at least a log of the startup of the server. Are you sure you've looked in the correct location? Check the Logging section in the Solr admin as well and adjust the logging level if necessary to show each request coming in to Solr.  Error creating document usually also ends up with a log message with a more concise error. Starting Solr with the `-f` parameter to keep the log in the foreground might help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

One of the fields is actually a char in the db but listed as an int in the configs. Must have been a mistype because it is an ID. Resolving that fixed the issue.

For some reason, the logs were still not being populated. I'm guessing something is improperly set up with SOLR and I'll have to let the team know.